# Can Jenkins run my shell script remotely?

Tags: bash, jenkins

A Bash script is CRON-ed to run on server A every day and connects to a remote MySQL database to run a query, dump the results to a file, and send an email.
In my freestyle project, I have set up my build to pull that Bash script from my Github repo and execute it.  Jenkins starts it but the script fails. Based on my discovery,

- Jenkins runs my script in a clone of my repo on its own server, not on server A where it is CRON-ed
- The above explains why my shell script fails to find the `mysql` client executable

Based on my understanding, this means that my freestyle project needs to connect to server A where my script is CRON-ed to run like so

```
ssh serverA_username@serverA #using ServerA user key
SCRIPT="$WORKSPACE/shell/bash_script_name.sh"
sh -x $SCRIPT
```

Am I correct? Any pointers welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you clone the repo if the script is already on the server?

Comment: You're right. It's redundant. I should simply be able to remotely log in to server A and run the script there since that's where it is.

Comment: Put the commands you're executing locally (ssh, script exec etc.) in a script and simply configure Jenkins to execute that script

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank you!